# Is it possible to use urllib to determine if two page links are related?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

Would it be possible to find out if a website is a 'subsite'. For example, scraping the [Wikipedia Math page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Mathematics) with urllib.urlparse will give me netlocs of:

`en.wiktionary.org
 zu.wikipedia.org
 id.wikipedia.org`

Which clearly derive from Wikipedia. But it also gives me:

`http://www.bbc.co.uk`

Which is not a derivative of Wikipedia. The problem is that netloc only recognizes absolute URLS. So I would assume that given a netloc the link is external to the scraped page, whereas a relative path with no netloc leaves me thinking that it belongs entirely to the current page scraped.

So is there a urllib function (or any library) that can differentiate between something like:
`zu.wikipedia.org`
and
`id.wikipedia.org`, the only option I think I have left at this point is resorting to regex which just doesn't seem in depth enough to determine if two websites are related/derived from one another or elsewhere.

Comment: This is the library I'm already using with python3, as the tags suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find a combination of the [yarl](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/) and [tldextract](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract) packages helpful for you here.  `tldextract` is based on the logic that a URL's host/netloc is broken into 3 parts:

- subdomain
- domain
- suffix (which can be nested, with multiple '.'), such as `.co.uk' or '.ac.gov.br' (Brazilian state ac)

For http://www.bbc.co.uk (you can include or exclude the scheme):

```
>>> import tldextract
>>> tldextract.extract('http://www.bbc.co.uk')
ExtractResult(subdomain='www', domain='bbc', suffix='co.uk')
```

Now to your question: it seems that you're interested in using both the `domain` and relative-versus-absolute nature of the path to determine whether A is a subsite of B.

Firstly, to address this up front, there is one part of your question that's a bit ambiguous: how, formally, is en.wiktionary.org a subsite of Wikipedia?  Because it is a relative URL?  Because it has the word "wiki" in it?  I'll assume it's the former, so that your rule system becomes:

- If the URL is relative, it is a subsite of the given page
- If the URL has the same domain, it is a subsite as well
- A third rule: cases like "//login.wikimedia.org" are also relative.  This is technically an absolute path, where a double slash followed by the authority is shorthand for "use the same scheme as what the parent is using".

As a function:

```
from yarl import URL
import tldextract

def is_subsite(child, parent):
    u = URL(child)
    if not u.scheme and child.startswith('//'):
        return True
    if not u.is_absolute():
        return True
    return (tldextract.extract(child).domain ==
            tldextract.extract(parent).domain)
```

Example:

```
>>> # Operates on the pretence that `child` was found on `parent` page HTML
>>> is_subsite("/wiki/Category:Algebraic_geometry", 
...            "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Mathematics")
True

>>> is_subsite("https://zu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ikhasi_Elikhulu",
...            "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Mathematics")
True

>>> is_subsite("//login.wikimedia.org",
...            "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Mathematics")
True
```

One disclaimer: You may want to rethink passing something like "zu.wikipedia.org," because, as far as I know, this is not actually a valid URL per RFC 3986.  (It has no scheme, and it's not relative either.  And I don't see it on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Mathematics, for what it's worth.)  So that means `URL("zu.wikipedia.org").is_absolute()` will return `False`.  (Don't think of yarl as a URL validator--it is better at URL manipulation & parsing.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. To my carelessness I should've mentioned that I am also using tldextract and have not included it in an attempt to the solution. However as for yarl, I was not aware of this library and seems to fit in almost perfectly with what I need. Also, as for zu.wikipedia.org, it's Wikipedia in the Zulu language, as for why It's not RFC 3986 I'm not too sure and in any case I would think of something to handle those special situations after I have this solved. This is excellent, much thanks.

Comment: @aeaglez what I meant in that case is that zu.wikipedia.org should be https://zu.wikipedia.org or https://zu.wikipedia.org.  Just "google.com" or "www.google.com" is not a valid URL.  When you type that in your browser, the internet browser is smart enough to add a scheme by default.

Comment: (Stack Overflow automatically converts the full `https://zu.wikipedia.org` links to their short-form)